# Reading serial AMA0 of Arduino writes an empty data

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I am connected Arduino to the Raspberry via **/dev/ttyACM0**.
Despite the python script I want to retrieve data from the Arduino, which is doing, but if you want the data to appear more frequently (1-4 seconds) and the data does not list any.
Data is written out irregularly me, which I do not understand :(

Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  Serial.print("25.78"); // temperature °C
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println();
}
```

Raspberry, python code:

```
import serial
serialport = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600, timeout=0.7)
response = serialport.readline()
print response
serialport.close()
```

Here is an excerpt:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python test.py

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python test.py

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python test.py


pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python test.py
25.78
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python test.py
25.78
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python test.py
25.78
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python test.py

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python test.py
```

I do not know how I could fix it to be 100% functional?

Comment: What's an Arduino Raspberry?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your read timeout (0.7s) is smaller than the frequency that you write the data (every 1000ms). So if you repeatedly execute the script that reads it, you'll sometimes miss the data. I'd recommend to either increase your read timeout, or decrease the interval that the Arduino sleeps.

Answer (score 0):

The script running on the Arduino is only generating output once a second. As a result, it may take up to one second for output to appear; there's no way to speed this up without changing the script running on the Arduino.

Additionally, since you currently have a timeout of 0.7 second set in your Python script, about 30% of runs will time out before any output appears. You'll need to change that to at least 1 second (ideally a bit more) for your script to work reliably.

A better solution, though, may be for the script running on the Arduino wait to read data from the serial port before generating output. (In other words, have the Arduino only 'speak' when 'spoken to'.)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't assume that the system you are using is buffering the serial data the Arduino is outputting.  Your application should do this by letting the read block for longer than 0.7s or running it in a loop.

```
import serial
serialport = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600, timeout=10)

while True:
    response = serialport.readline()
    if not response: print "Haven't received input in 10s"
    print response

serialport.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

How would the script if I over Raspberry sent via serial should be number one, and thanks to the Arduino sent the actual temperature.